# Why is it called assembly?

Tags: assembly

As the title suggests, I'm just wondering why the language is called assembly. I had a feeling that someone must have already asked the question, but I couldn't find it. Thanks.

Comment: A better question might be, "Why is it called an [assembler](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language)?"

Comment: An assembler assembles instructions into a program. That's how I understand it.

Comment: Back in the old days second generation languages (which assembly languages were classified as), the process of taking human readable mnemonics and converting it into machine readable form was a process called _assembly_ . Since the process was called _assembly_, that class of languages took on that name  _assembly languages_ .

Comment: Michael Petch, this would work as an answer.

Answer (score -3):

Here's what Wikipedia says:

"Assembly languages, and the use of the word assembly, date to the introduction of the stored-program computer. The Electronic Delay Storage Automatic Calculator (EDSAC) had an assembler called initial orders featuring one-letter mnemonics in 1949.[18] SOAP (Symbolic Optimal Assembly Program) was an assembly language for the IBM 650 computer written by Stan Poley in 1955."

You can read the full article here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language

Comment: I don't think that answered my question. I'm wondering more in the sense of "what does the language have to do with the original meaning of the word assembly?".

Comment: @user4034932 I would say it has everything to do with the proper meaning of *assembly* - "building a structure from parts".